# Resizing / caching JPEG images on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a website written in .NET 4.5 / MVC 4 that allows users to upload images, among other things. These images can be displayed throughout the site in a variety of sizes. Currently, the way this works is as follows:

- The image is uploaded and re-sized in memory to a max width of 640px (the largest the site will display).
- The resized image is saved to disk at /assets/photos/source/{id}-{timestamphash}.jpg.
- When a request for the image in various sizes comes through, I get the filename by combining {id}-{hash} where {hash} is the hash of a combination of ids, height, width and some other information I need to get the image.
- If that image exists in /assets/photos/cache, I simply return it, otherwise I create it in memory using the source image and then save it to the cache directory.

I like this approach because it happens quickly and it all happens in-memory or via disk retrieval.

I'd like to eventually move my site to Azure. How would a workflow like this happen in Azure given that all of my images would be stored as blobs? Is it still efficient to use a re-sizing/caching strategy like this or are there other alternatives? Wouldn't you incur network latency as the image is uploaded to Azure from the server where today, it just gets saved to disk which is obviously a lot faster?

Just looking for some direction on how to migrate a workflow like this to something workable and scalable with Azure.

Comment: Do you know beforehand the different sizes that could be requested?

Comment: Yeah I have a list of acceptable sizes to prevent someone from flooding my assets server with requests for infinite combinations of sizes and filling the hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment above, why not create a background task that resizes to all acceptable sizes on upload, storing each one into the Azure blob storage.  You are correct that if you resize on request, you would suffer some latency and lag as you would need to download the source image, resize, then upload to blob storage, then redirect the user to your blob storage url.  Given the 'cheapness' of blob storage, I would submit that paying a few dimes more for extra storage would outweight the potential slowness of the scenario above.

Pseudo Code Below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedBaseFile file){
   if(ValidateFile(file)){
      //fire off a background tasks that resizes and stores each file size to the azure
      //blog storage.  You could use a naming scheme such as id_size.imageTypeExtension
   } 
}
```

Now, when asked for a file, you could still use your same routine,  but instead of returning a file result, you would return a redirect result

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string hash){
    //do stuff to get image details
    return Redirect("http://yourAzureBlobStorageDomain.com/Assets/Images/Cache/" + imageDetails")
}
```

This is cool because you don't need to download the image to your web server and then serve it, but simply redirect the request directly to the blob storage!  This would have the affect that an image tag such as below

`<img src="@Url.RouteUrl("GetImage", "Images" new {hash = hash})"/>`  would hit your web application, forcing a redirect to the actual image location in blob storage.

You are correct that you do not want to store anything on the Azure web role permanently as the web roles can be moved around at any time, losing any locally stored data.

This is just a simple way to sort of keep your code base the way it is now with minimal changes.  You could modify this to behave more like what you have now in that you could query the blob storage if an image exists, if it does, redirect, if it does not then generate, store and redirect, but I believe you would find you will have more issues with the latency at this point given you would need to download the source image, do your stuff and then reupload the image before instructing the user's browser where to go find it.

However, this would be something for you to decide if it was worth the extra time it would take to resize on demand vs the cost of storing multiple sizes of each image.  As a side note, we have not noticed a significant latency issue when using blob storage from our web/worker roles.  Obviously it is higher than retrieval from disks, but it has not really posed a significant increase that we have been able to see.

Comment: Actually this works with private blobs as well. You'd just need to append a Shared Access Signature to the URI.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - oh, cool to know!  Ill take that line out of my answer.

Comment: My only concern with this approach is that there's some lag time between uploading and the other sizes being available. Currently the user uploads the image and is immediately redirected to a view which shows them one of the smaller sizes. I'll mark this as the answer since it was a thorough answer and points me in the right direction. If you have any thoughts on how to get the smaller sizes to be available right away, I'd like to hear them.

Comment: @Scott - My initial thought would be you could return the smaller size directly from the controller/action as a File Result or...this would be a good time to use the local storage (temp, short lived file) to help with the current limitation.  You would need to add some logic around this however to ensure additional request down the road are redirected to the proper location (user page refresh, etc)